# Keeping link in an inactive state while menu is open

Tags: jquery, html, menu

So, I have a menu that pushes out from the left when the 'KH' logo is clicked. When the 'KH' is hovered over, it goes to a lighter grey colour.

Once the 'KH' is clicked and the user moves their mouse it goes back to the active state of black.

Is there a way to keep the 'KH' at this lighter grey colour the whole time the menu is open, and only go back to black once the user closes the menu?

HTML:

```
<div class="logo"><button class="one toggle-menu menu-left push-body">KH</button></div>
```

CSS:

```
button.one {
border : 0px;
background: #f4f4f4;
font-family: "bebas-neue", sans-serif;
font-size: 3em;
color: #272727;
font-weight: 400;
padding-bottom: 15px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
}

button.one:active { color: #ccc; }

button.one:hover { color: #ccc; cursor: pointer; }
```

Website: http://kaye.at/babyboom.php

Comment: I updated my answer and it works - check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/dcRZA/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way, you would need to edit the `/js/classie.js` file.
I have a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/dcRZA/2/)

Specifically:

```
//...
var jPushMenu = {
            close: function (o) {
                $('.jPushMenuBtn,body,.cbp-spmenu').removeClass('disabled active cbp-spmenu-open cbp-spmenu-push-toleft cbp-spmenu-push-toright');
                                // Add the below line
                                $('button.one').css('color', '#272727');
            }
        }
```

Then also remove the :hover attribute from your css file and amend this script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('button.one').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).css('color', '#CCC');
    });
    $('button.one').on('mouseout', function () {
        if ($('.cbp-spmenu-open').length == 0) {
            $(this).css('color', '#272727');
        }
    });
    $('.toggle-menu').jPushMenu();
});
```

Comment: Okay, figured it out and all seems to work, but only works the once? If I click the menu closed, then try to click it open again, it no longer works? It's happening in the jsfiddle also.

Comment: I updated it changing the class we're looking for to `cbp-spmenu-open`  It seems to be working consistently now.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to have

```
button.one:active { color: #ccc; }
```

changed to something like

```
button.one:active, .button_active { color: #ccc; }
```

and add this anywhere in your script (After the dom is ready):

```
$(".logo button").click(function () { $(this).toggleClass("active_button"); })
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of an amateur with writing Javascript. What JS code exactly would I need to get this to work?

Comment: change the CSS to what I suggested, and add the script line (new one, edited) to your scripts in your page.

Comment: Thank you! Doesn't seem to work though. :( When menu is opened and user moves their cursor, it still returns to black.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a hover-specific style when clicked, and then apply this style when clicked, and removing it when necessary?  For example:

```
button.one.hover,
button.one:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NjRzf/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. As soon as cursor is moved (with menu open), the text goes back to black. I need it to stay grey until user clicks off and closes menu.

Comment: Did you see the attached jsFiddle in my post? If you hover over the icon it goes grey, at which point it will revert back to black if not clicked.  If clicked it will stay grey until the `someOtherContainer` is clicked.